# How to open a port on MacOS X

Tags: unix, macos, network

I previously had Memcache running on my localhost/127.0.0.1 port 11211. Unfortunately, I rebooted my computer and now port 11211 isn't open and I don't know the command to open this port.

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to start memcache by typing

`memcached`

in terminal and leaving the window open

or start the daemon

`memcached -d`

you could also look for a loadctrl script if you want this to always run on boot.

Comment: -@j_mcnally, thanks that worked. Can you explain the difference -/+ the daemon `-d` flag? I'm not sure what a daemon is.

Comment: runs in background / detached from the terminal

Comment: Meaning i can close the terminal window in which i typed the command and the port will stay open? It would seem like you'd want that all the time. What would be an example of a scenario where you won't use the `-d` flag?

Comment: when you want to see the output in terminal rather than logging, useful for debugging.

Comment: you could alternative use something like 'screen' and detach the terminal entirely but still get the output when you reattach to it. the choice is yours. Also you could say `memcached &` which will background the task but still print STDOUT and STDERR to the terminal, while still allowing you to use the terminal.